# How can I extract a list of Tuple from a specific table with Entity Framework / LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, list

I need to extract a list of couple 'ID'/'Name' from a large table in C# .NET with Entity Framework.

I try this request :

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> list = (from res in db.Resource 
                                 select new Tuple<int, string>(res.Resource_ID, res.Name)).ToList();
```

But unfortunately I've got this error :

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

I don't undestand how can I extract this list of tuple with this framework and I feel a bit lost with this error.
Can you help me to understand and resolve my problem ?

Best regards,

Alex

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it with a middle-step by selecting an anonymous type:

```
db.Resource.Select(x => new { x.Resource_ID, x.Name }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Resource_ID, x.Name)).ToList();
```

Creating a tuple is not a supported operation in Linq To Entities, so you have to select an anonymous type, which would be an equivalent to:

```
SELECT [Resource].[Resource_ID], [Resource].[Name]
```

then move to LINQ to  Objects by `AsEnumerable` and get your tuple.

Comment: +1 for using the anonymous type to reduce the amount of data being transferred from the DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list from `db.Resource` and use *LINQ to Collections* to erase this limitation:

```
var list = db.Resource.ToList().Select(res => Tuple.Create(res.Resource_ID, res.Name));
```

The `Tuple` class does have some constructors (up to 8 items), but the [`Create()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.tuple.create%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) helper method makes the creation more straightforward.

Comment: Good, I'm glad it helps you.

Comment: @fuex  Easy to understand. Thanks

Comment: The Tuple class does have a constructor. See:
var tuple = new Tuple<string,string>(res.Resource_ID, res.Name);