# Tuples - Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, tuples

I want to load a list of tuples from database. However, when tried like below. I am getting an error "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities".

```
List<Tuple<string, DateTime?>> schdule = new List<Tuple<string, DateTime?>>();
schdule = Entities.ScheduleDates.Where(x => x.Code == cCode).Select(x => new Tuple<string, DateTime?>(x.Key, x.Time)).ToList<Tuple<string, DateTime?>>();
```

However, by using anonymous types I don't get any error.

```
var tempSchedule = Entities.ScheduleDates.Where(x => x.Code == cCode).Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Time }).ToList();
```

Why I am facing the above error.

Comment: because _Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities_

Comment: Duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/a/13875074, maybe [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13875074/19046) "If you still want to use your constructor for initialization and not properties (...), enumerate the query by calling ToList() or ToArray(), and then use Select(…)." is more useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Because **LINQ to Entities** queries are translated to **SQL** queries, so each operation you do must have an equivalent in SQL.

Constructors which are nothing more than methods can't be translated.

But instantiating an anonymous type can, it will simply be translated as:

```
SELECT someAlias.Key, someAlias.Time ...
```

Comment: Thanks.. I wanted to Know this.

Comment: That's cool but I cannot access fields in my anonymous class when I'm iterating through the collection in Razor

Comment: @CsabaToth You mean you have a runtime error?

Comment: @Pragmateek Yes, during Razor evaluation. I went with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542761/how-can-i-extract-a-list-of-tuple-from-a-specific-table-with-entity-framework