# How to join 2 tables using linq but avoid anonymous object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, strong-typing

I want to join 2 tables using linq and avoid anonymous object.

So far i use tuple.

```
var products = from tm in db.TargetMarkets
                join tp in db.Products on tm.product_id equals tp.id
                where tm.country == 2
                select Tuple.Create<TargetMarket, Product>(tm, tp);
```

But, when i foreach

```
foreach (var p in products)
{
    var a = p.Item1.id;
}
```

It throws an exception

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Tuple`2

**Question**:

1. Is there a way to keep my code strongly typed
2. What's wrong with tuple (optional)

Comment: I suspect error is because of types used join condition, can you check both Ids are of same type?

Comment: You notice error in `foreach` because the first statement is deferred exectution.

Comment: They are same types (integer). query statement not throwing the error. foreach execution throws the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep my code strong type

You can define a new type and make object of that type instead of anonymous object.

```
class ProductTargetMarket
{
   //Attributes
} 

var ProductsTargetMarkets = from tm in db.TargetMarkets
            join tp in db.Products on tm.product_id equals tp.id
            where tm.country == 2
            select new ProductTargetMarket{Attribute1OfProductTargetMarket = tp.Attribute1, Attribute1OfProductTargetMarket = tm.Attribute1 };
```

To create a tuple you may first convert it to anonymous type and then convert it to tuple, see this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118688/return-tuple-from-ef-select) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542761/how-can-i-extract-a-list-of-tuple-from-a-specific-table-with-entity-framework) post.

Comment: Thanks. it works!. i just wondering "linq query" syntax for, first return anonymous type and convert it to tuple. (optional & googled) :)